# Disable building package in maven release plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I am both new to maven and the maven release plugin but what I am trying to achieve here is simple. I am able to use the maven release plugin using the command `mvn release:prepare` just fine however I don't want it to execute running the the entire build before bumping up the pom. I just want it to bump up the pom when I use it. How do I disable it from executing that goal?

Answer (score 3):

The maven release plugin executes the goals specified in `preparationGoals` property, which are, by default, "clean verify".

Override the value of this property either through the plugin configuration:

```xml
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
      <configuration>
        <preparationGoals></preparationGoals>
        <!-- your other configuration -->
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

or on the command line:

```
mvn release:prepare -DpreparationGoals= ...
```

to specify whatever other goals you might want to execute instead. For example, setting it to `initialize` or to an empty string all together.

Answer (score 1):

You meant, you want to skip the "build" of the project when run the prepare goal?

If so, as far i know, it cannot be done, as the prepare is a ***mandatory step*** for a prepare. In fact the prepare check

1. If all the dependencies are resolved with the given versions.
2. If the resolved dependencies permit the build of the project.

From the official documentation ([Link](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html)): 
Preparing a release goes through the following release phases:

1. Check that there are no uncommitted changes in the sources
2. Check that there are no SNAPSHOT dependencies
3. Change the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version (you will be prompted for the versions to use)
4. Transform the SCM information in the POM to include the final destination of the tag
5. **Run the project tests against the modified POMs to confirm everything is in working order**
6. Commit the modified POMs
7. Tag the code in the SCM with a version name (this will be prompted for)
8. Bump the version in the POMs to a new value y-SNAPSHOT (these values will also be prompted for)
9. Commit the modified POMs

Comment: Yeah I read that but I thought there might be a way to override the default configurations in some way

Comment: I used the prepare for looong time... and for his nature, i don't think there is... sorry :(